# Current drawn by a permanent magnet DC motor

Tags: current, dc-motor

I have been working with PMDC motors for a while now. In these motors, as the load increases current drawn by the motor also increases. I was just wondering what is the theoretical reason behind this change in current?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the motor spins, the magnetic field induces back EMF in the windings. The induced voltage has opposite polarity than the supply voltage. Theoretically, when no load is present, these voltages cancel out and no current can flow.

When the motor is loaded and slowed down, the BEMF voltage decreases and allows more current to flow. When the motor is stalled, there is no BEMF and current is limited only by winding resistance.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Could you tell me the mathematical expression for this BEMF?

Comment: @abhi1221 Sure. \$v_b(t)=K_b\frac{d\theta _m(t)}{dt}\$ or \$V_b(s)=K_bs\theta _m(s)\$. \$V_b\$ is BEMF voltage, \$\theta _m\$ is angle, \$K_b\$ is back emf constant which is defined as \$\frac{e_a}{\omega _{no-load}}\$. \$e_a\$ is the supply DC voltage. By the way, it is from [this book](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-EHEP001820.html)

Answer (score 1):

Every electrical machine has two key constants associated with it

K\$_E\$ = BackEMF constant  \$\approx\$ V/\$\omega\$ (machine topology dependant)

K\$_T\$ = Torque constant \$\approx\$ Nm/A (machine topology dependant)

Theoretically they are the same, practically K\$_T\$ is defined at maximum current and thus it contains aspects of stator saturation.

Now as K\$_T\$ is defined as Torque per Amp  ( Nm/A) so more amps equates to more torque.

But why does current equate to torque?  essentially the stator is one big electro-magnet. If you pass current through it a magnetic field is created. Increase the current and a stronger magnetic field is created.

A PMDC machine is essentially a synchronous machine (with its corePack machined & the rotor magnets aligned such to provide a trapezoidal-like BackEMF) so... if an AC signal is applied to the stator windings, an AC airgap field will be generated and the rotor will attempt to "lock on" and rotate with the field.

As to the original question though

> I have been working with PMDC motors for a while now. In these motors,
>   as the load increases current drawn by the motor also increases. I was
>   just wondering what is the theoretical reason behind this change in
>   current?

This actually isn't unique to PMDC machine, or PMAC machine, Induction, etc.. but motor-controllers.
An increase in load at the rotor will attempt to slow the rotor down. With a BLDC machine connected to a speed-controller, it will attempt to counter the slowdown in rotor speed by increasing the current demand and thus increase the torque generated to oppose the load torque.

Now simple BLDC controller which only manage commutation rather than current control will equally experience this because the commutator will energize the coils in sequence and the rotor will just accelerate ( \$\omega = \int T(t)/J\$ ) until the BackEMF = Applied voltage 
As the rotor load is increased this maximum speed can no longer be maintained as there is a need to provide higher current & thus:

Terminal voltage > BackEMF + \$L_w + R_w\$

So... the speed must decrease to facilitate an increase in current == increase in torque

Answer (score 0):

As the load increases it draws mechanical power out of the motor. That power has to come from somewhere. Power in = voltage x current. Power out = torque x rpm. Torque results from passing current through the stator windings at right angles to the magnetic field created by the permanent magnets in the rotor ([Lorentz Force Law](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/magfor.html#c2)).

If the motor had superconducting windings (ie. zero resistance) then it would not slow down at all under load. The back-emf would remain equal to the supply voltage, and the motor would draw just enough extra current to create the torque required to keep it spinning at constant speed. However normal wire *does* have resistance, and this drops a voltage proportional to current ([Ohm's Law](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/ohmlaw.html)). That voltage subtracts from the back-emf, so the motor slows down.